# How to hide a div class in Wordpress? CSS

Tags: css

This is my Div Class, I have included the entire code below. I need to hide this on Wordpress on my site. How do I go about it?

I tried .

```
section_wrapper clearfix {
    display : none;
}
```

In Custom CSS but does not work. How do I hide this?

`<div class="section_wrapper clearfix">`

Example Code Below:

```
<div class="section_wrapper clearfix">

    <!-- additional HTML content -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since section_wrapper and clearfix are classes so to give them styling you have to include .(dot) before them and you have to use only one among 2 of them.

for example

```
.section_wrapper{
display:none;
}
```

If you write like this

```
.section_wrapper .clearfix{
    display:none;
    }
```

It means you are giving styling to the element having class clearfix which is under the element having class section_wrapper

Answer (score 1):

You need to target them as classes in CSS (i.e. with `.`s in front of the class names). Also, since the classes are from the same element, you need to get rid of the space between the class names:

```
.section_wrapper.clearfix {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: On a related note, I highly recommend you [read about CSS selectors and how to use them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors).

Answer (score -1):

Try hiding a specific div ID like so:

```
<div id="ab-reblog-box">
```

Comment: Do you need an answer to that question? Or is it a rhetoric question which you intend to serve as an answer according to [answer] to the question at the top of this page?